# Android manifest intent filter error?

Tags: android-intent, filter, manifest

YO!

Im making a working button, i got help and tips from youtube videos, but im getting an error im my manifest which i cant sus-out.. Heres the end of the android manifest in code

```
    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.tssandroid.phone.buttonOne"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.tssandroid.phone.TUTORIALONE" />
          <cetegory android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.tssandroid.phone.TUTORIALONE" />
    <cetegory android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<intent-filter>
```

`<intent-filter>` doesn't have a closing tag.

Should be:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.tssandroid.phone.TUTORIALONE" />
    <cetegory android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

PS: Your question was very badly formed. Next time include the error or be more clear about the problem.